How to get the GRUB menu to show up at boot-time in Ubuntu 24.04 and/or 22.04 on MacBookPro7,1 (mid-2010 13")
I tried all of the solutions in How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time?, but nothing seems to work.

The missing piece from How to get to the GRUB menu at boot-time? seems to be that Ubuntu 24.04 and 22.04 (and possibly other releases as well) can't get this MacBook Pro's Nvidia GPU (GeForce 320M) to show a higher-resolution graphical terminal, so you have to force it into the "text mode".
You can do this by editing /etc/default/grub: simply uncomment the line GRUB_TERMINAL=console. And then don't forget to run sudo update-grub.
The full steps:

Open /etc/default/grub as admin - e.g. by running gnome-text-editor admin:///etc/default/grub or sudo nano /etc/default/grub

Make sure that GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE is NOT commented out and set it to menu as opposed to hidden
Make sure that GRUB_TIMEOUT is NOT commented out and set it to 5 as opposed to 0 - it's in seconds
Make sure that GRUB_TERMINAL is NOT commented out and set it to console
If you'd also like to see on your screen the kernel and systemd log messages during booting instead of the splash screen (the Ubuntu logo with a spinner underneath it), also change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""


Run sudo update-grub

